# How can I assign a Task to a Guest user?

Tags: podio

I am attempting to assign a Task using the Podio API to a guest user.
I can do this *easily* through the Podio Web Interface (I do it all the time) but why can't I do this with the API?
Here is my basic code:

```
$resp_profiles[] = array(
  'type' => 'profile',
  'id' => 4346424);

 PodioTask::create(array(
    'text' => $subTitle,
    'description' => $subTitle,
    'private' => false,
    'due_on' => $task_due_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'responsible' => $resp_profiles, 
  ));
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PodioForbiddenError: 
"Must be at least light on user 4346424 to perform this operation" 
Request URL: http://api.podio.com/task/ 
Stack Trace: 
#0 /home/avcorp/vhosts/pubvps/vendor/podio/podio-php/lib/Podio.php(352): Podio::request('POST', '/task/', Array, Array) 
#1 /home/avcorp/vhosts/pubvps/vendor/podio/podio-php/models/PodioTask.php(78): Podio::post('/task/', Array) 
#2 /home/avcorp/vhosts/pubvps/podio_rmticket/rmticket_util.php(309): PodioTask::create(Array) 
#3 /home/avcorp/vhosts/pubvps/podio_rmticket/rmticket_util.php(152): rmtCreateTask(Object(AvcPodioItem), 'Carpet Cleaning', 10, 3) 
#4 /home/avcorp/vhosts/pubvps/podio_rmticket/poll/rmticket_poll.php(54): test_task_creation() 
#5 {main} thrown in /home/avcorp/vhosts/pubvps/vendor/podio/podio-php/lib/Podio.php on line 319
```

Comment: Please clarify what is profile 4346424 and how is script authenticated? Most likely you can't assign task to user because your script doesn't have access to that user.

Comment: Auth is a user with Admin rights to that Workspace.

Comment: User 4346424 is a Guest user listed in the "members" pages as: Type = External, Role = Guest.
I can assign tasks to this user using the Podio Website, but not with the API.

Comment: It would also be nice to know what this means:
  // https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/create-task-22419
  //   "responsible": The contact(s) responsible for the task, identified by either:
  //    An integer (user_id)
  //    A {"type": contact identifier type, "id": contact identifier value} object
  //    A list of integers and/or contact identifier objects
  //       (with 5 supported contact identifier types: "user", "profile", "mail", "space", "external"),

What is the format and constraints for each of those "5 supported contact identifier types"?

Answer (score 0):

From Podio help page: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201019898-Member-roles-in-workspaces

> Guests are users that have been invited to selected items using the
>   share item tool. They can edit and comment these specific items, but
>   cannot see anything else within the workspace, such as the full list
>   of members, other information in the app, or other apps in the same
>   workspace.

Have you tried changing role to 'Light' ?
That will also explain error message: `Must be at least light on user 4346424 to perform this operation`

You cannot assign a task to guest user profile even from frontend. It might be a bit confusing because you can assign task to user using `mail` user identifier, but that is restricted to Podio highly trusted partners only.

Comment: No. Because I don't *want* them to be a Light user. Light users can see ALL AppItem entries. That will be confusing for this user to see a list of dozens of other items that have nothing to do with them. The real question (which I asked originally) is: Why CAN I assign tasks to this user using the Web interface and I CAN'T using the API? 
Supposedly, the "entire Podio website is building using the API"...from my experience, I doubt that...

Comment: So when I'm assigning it in the Website, I'm actually using "mail" type. (again, would be nice if this was DOCUMENTED).
I had already tried the "mail" type.
Here is what I received when I tried that:
Fatal error: Uncaught PodioForbiddenError: "Only available for clients with a trust level of 2 or higher. To get your API client upgraded to a higher trust level contact support at support@podio.com." 

How do I get upgraded to "trust level of 2"?

Comment: You follow instructions and contact support at support@podio.com :)